# AR Query returning a relation instead of the expected object type (model person)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Queries returning different object types based on using limit() or first

This example uses limit(1) and does not produce the expected object type:

```
c =  PersonCategory.where("category = ?", "Crown").limit(1) ##
=> PersonCategory Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `person_categories`.* FROM `person_categories` WHERE (category = 'Crown') LIMIT 1
=> [#<PersonCategory id: 1, category: "Crown">]  #####
c.class
=> ActiveRecord::Relation
```

This example uses first and gives the desired output:

```
c =  PersonCategory.where("category = ?", "Crown").first ##
=> PersonCategory Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `person_categories`.* FROM `person_categories` WHERE (category = 'Crown') LIMIT 1
=> #<PersonCategory id: 1, category: "Crown"> 
c.class
=> PersonCategory(id: integer, category: string)   #####
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :034 >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`limit` returns a limited set of results.  In your case, it returns what is essentially an array of `PersonCategory` objects, even if you only specify one object with `limit(1)`.

For instance, calling `PersonCategory.limit(15)` would return the first 15 `PersonCategory` items in your database.

`first`, on the other hand, only returns the first result of it's preceding query - **not** an array of results.  That's why you would see an individual `PersonCategory` object being returned.